# Is there a better way to handle default value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There are *too many* times I have write something reassembling this:

```js
const foo = some_expression ? some_expression : some_default_value;
```

This is really long already and normally an expression would be even longer. Is there a concise way to do this in JS/TS?

I know I can define a function but this is still not ideal in my opinion.

Comment: Just `some_expression || some_default_value`? What is the type of `foo`, are you dealing with strings, booleans, nullable values, something else?

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo = truthy || whatever;
```

If they are parameters passed into your function you can set a default when passed:

```
function foo(bar = 'biz') {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const foo = some_expression || some_default_value
```

for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR